# Session variables unset between page content changes

Tags: php

i am using 1 index.php page and using navigation links to send values $_GET values which are used to retrieve page content from mysql database to effectively change the page which is working fine.
On one of the nav links a session variable is set when clicked which i want to use later, but when i click another nav link that doesnt set sessions the previously set session has been unset and so has no value. i have checked the session_id which is the same on each page and have checked that the session variable is actually being set by outputing to the screen, it just disappears when a new page is clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think (but someone will correct if I am wrong) that you should start the session all over you website for the session to be kept in place. Try to add `session_start();` at the top of all your pages and see if things improve. `$_GET` is not related to the session so it is unclear to me why you mention it...

Comment: Thanks I have tried that. It seems that the sessions and variables are working ok but I have located the line that is causing the problem, "$_SESSION['district'] = $_GET['district'];. When the page with this line is run if a "district" value is sent in the url the $_SESSION['district'] is set to that value. The problem is if no "district" value is sent in the url, the line $_SESSION['district'] = $_GET['district']; sets the $_SESSION['district'] to a blank. I don't understand why this is ?

Comment: sessions can be empty. Actually, if you don't set the session variables properly, they're set to null (empty). You should check if the variable is empty. Something like if (isset($_SESSION['district']) && $_SESSION['district'] !== "")or first che if it's set, then check if it's empty.

Comment: if i load the page and set $_SESSION['district'] to 4, i then checked the value of of $_SESSION['district'] and it returns as 4 so it has been set. I then removed the line of code that sets it $_SESSION['district'] = $_GET['district']; and load the page again. now i check the value of $_SESSION['district']and it has been set to either NULL or Blank (i havent checked that yet) even though there is no code to even set that variable !

Comment: that's because you have to set the $_SESSION['disctrict'], I presume. Otherwise it gets set to null. I discovered this myself, when writing a login script. The $_SESSION['userid'] in my case was set, but was blank (so it's worthless to check if the session is set, on a login page. It can be set, and be blank).